# Javascript loop not seeing asp labels

Tags: javascript, loops, label

I have the following javascript in an asp page:

```
for (var i=0; i < form1.elements.length; i++) {
    var elm = form1.elements[i];
    alert(elm.name)
}
```

When I iterate throught I see the viewstate and I see the asp buttons but I do not see the asp labels. Is that the expected behavior?  How can I iterate through the labels?

Answer (score 1):

not too familiar with asp, but I am pretty sure label tags are not part of the form's elements property. Try something like this

```
var labels = form1.getElementsByTagName("LABEL");
for(var i=0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    alert(labels[i].id);
}
```

Comment: going by what @amig_g says (ASP labels are rendered as SPAN tags), try replacing `code`var labels = form1.getElementsByTagName("LABEL");`code` for `code`var labels = form1.getElementsByTagName("SPAN");`code` (But that might give you all the spans in the form, then you need to select which ones you need or not.

Answer (score 0):

ASP labels render as SPAN tag and SPAN tag is not part of the forms collection. While you can iterate through the SPAN collection with code given by medina-g (use SPAN instead of LABEL), the typical HTML page may have a lot of spans.

Comment: The username of previous poster.